# How to put Char** into _stprintf

Tags: c++

I have this code. I would like to put argv[1] as prefix to fileName. How do I do that?

```
int _tmain(int argc, char** argv)
{
...
    _stprintf(fileName, _T("%04d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%03d.jpeg"), lt.wYear, lt.wMonth, lt.wDay, lt.wHour, lt.wMinute, lt.wSecond, lt.wMilliseconds);
```

Comment: For readability, I suggest the shorter `20100904-123405.jpeg` name; that is easier to read than `2010-09-04-12-34-05.jpeg`.  It you keep the divided form, then I recommend using something different to separate the date and the time components: `2010-09-04.12:34:05.jpeg` perhaps (or maybe colons are persona non grata; maybe a `T` to separate date from time?).  (But I do commend you for using the ISO 8601 notation with year before month before day, and for remembering the lessons of Y2K!)

Comment: Good point its much easier to read this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_stprintf(fileName, _T("%s-%04d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%03d.jpeg"), argv[1], lt.wYear, lt.wMonth, lt.wDay, lt.wHour, lt.wMinute, lt.wSecond, lt.wMilliseconds);
```

That will do what you want, but since you're using C++ you would be best to use a stringstream instead.

```
#include <stringstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << argv[1] << "-" << lt.wYear << "-" << lt.wMonth << "-" << lt.wDay << "-" << lt.wHour << "-" << lt.wMinute << "-" << lt.wSecond << "-" << lt.wMilliseconds << ".jpeg";
}
```

You can then access the string with `ss.str()`. You can also use the same stream format modifiers you would use with any output stream.

Comment: Is that going to give the correct 2-digit-with-leading-zero formats?

Comment: @Jonathan Only if you use the `setw(n)` stream manipulator to set the output field width.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the wholly non-standard `_stprintf()` is closely related to `sprintf()`, then:

- Use `%s` at the point in the format string where the name goes.
- Pass `argv[1]` at the corresponding point in the argument list.

Note that `argv` has the type `char **`; therefore, `argv[1]` has the type `char *`.